# Pyspark check if values from a column exists in another dataframe's column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to solve a problem where I have two pyspark dataframes with the following details:

```
df1
| value |
| ----- |
| the   |
| quick |
| brown |
| fox   |
| brown |


df2
| value  |
| ------ |
| brown  |
| fox    |
| brown  |
```

I need to output a new flag that checks whether values from `df1.value` exists in `df2.value`

```
output
 | value | flag |
 | ----- |----- |
 | the   |  0   |
 | quick |  0   |
 | brown |  1   |
 | fox   |  1   | 
 | brown |  1   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(
    df1
    .join(df2.withColumn("flag",F.lit(1)).distinct(), on="value", how="left_outer")
    .fillna(0)
)
```

Output:

```
|value|flag|
+-----+----+
|  fox|   1|
|  the|   0|
|brown|   1|
|brown|   1|
|quick|   0|
+-----+----+
```

An option without a join:

```
df1.withColumn(
    "flag",
    F.col('value').isin(list(df2.distinct().toPandas()['value'])).cast('int')
    )
```

Comment: Doing this toPandas distinct then list is very costly, do we've any other option ? Although it works, Thanks!